# Inconsistent results with Perceptron algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to implement the perceptron algorithm but am getting inconsistent results; I have noticed that the initialization of the weights is having a big impact. Is there anything I am blatantly doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

def train(x,y):

    lenWeights = len(x[1,:]);
    weights = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=lenWeights)
    bias = np.random.uniform(-1,1);
    learningRate = 0.01;
    t = 1;
    converged = False;

# Perceptron Algorithm

while not converged and t < 100000:
    targets = [];
    for i in range(len(x)):

            # Calculate output of the network
            output = ( np.dot(x[i,:],weights) ) + bias;

            # Perceptron threshold decision
            if (output > 0):
                target = 1;
            else:
                target = 0;

            # Calculate error and update weights
            error = target - y[i];

            weights = weights + (x[i,:] * (learningRate * error) );

            bias = bias + (learningRate * error);

            targets.append(target);

            t = t + 1;

    if ( list(y) == list(targets) ) == True:
        converged = True;


return weights,bias

def test(weights, bias, x):

    predictions = [];

    for i in range(len(x)):

        # Calculate w'x + b
        output = ( np.dot(x[i,:],weights) ) + bias;

        # Get decision from hardlim function
        if (output > 0):
            target = 1;
        else:
            target = 0;

        predictions.append(target);

    return predictions

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Simple Test

    x = np.array( [  [0,1], [1,1] ] );
    y = np.array( [ 0, 1 ] );

    weights,bias = train(x,y);
    predictions = test(weights,bias,x);

    print predictions
    print y
```

Comment: In what way are the results inconsistent? What is the dependence on weights that you found? I guess there is also an indentation error at the `while`.

Comment: Sometimes it outputs the correct labels while sometimes it doesn't, sort of random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perceptron is **not** globally optimized, so training results **won't** be consistent (they can vary each time you run your algorithm), and it depends on (among others) on weights initialization. This is the characteristics of gradient optimization of non-convex functions (which trianing a perceptron is an example of), not an implementation issue.

Comment: @lejlot The code in question is a simple binary one-layer perceptron. I think it should always converge globally if the training set is linearly separable and not converge at all if it isn't. The code in question does actually almost never converge. The questioner hid this with the `t < 100000` test. I also think the training set is linearly separable. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, I did assume more complex model (MLP). I would delete the answer, but first author has to "un-answer" it.

Comment: Yeah, it was a simple bug with my weight update on this line of code:

'error = target - y[i]';

It should have been:

'error = 'y[i] - target';

That fixed the problem for me; it always returns the correct result now as Nabla mentioned, as the training set is linearly separable.

Comment: Not quite---it's consistent because in the single layer case it's a convex optimisation problem. Your data don't have to be linearly separable for this to hold.